# Activities interaction

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 `Activities`, let the `Activity` `A` is the main `Activity` from which `B` and `C` `Activities` are called. `B` is `Activity` with settings, and `C` is `Activity` with the main actions. I need to realize `ToggleButton` in `B` which is responsible for whether the device will vibrate after pressing the buttons in `C`. Thus, it is necessary to connect `B` and `C`. If using Intent, it is necessary to call the `StartActivity (Intent)/StartActivityForResult (Intent)` method. From this it follows that when pressing `ToggleButton` in `B`, the `C` will be called by `B`. And it is unnecessary to me. I need that when pressing `ToggleButton` "something" was remembered "somewhere", and then when the `C` is called it will be cause to device vibrating. How to solve this problem?

Comment: If you need the value to persist then use sharedPreference. Alternatively, you can use static variables. Check this http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Android-Design

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189476/public-static-variables-and-android-activity-life-cycle-management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SharedPreferences to store some states, eg:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

editor.putString("key_string", "jack");
editor.putInt("key_int", 30);
editor.putBoolean("vibrator", false);

editor.commit();
```

Then you can read it when you need it:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String name = prefs.getString("key_string", "defaultName");
int age = prefs.getInt("key_int", 25);
boolean vib = prefs.getBoolean("vibrator", true);
```

Basically, SharedPreferences store key-value pairs. Read more about them [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Answer (score 1):

[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is probably the best way to handle this. In `Activity B` create a SharedPreferences for vibrate, set to the boolean value "true" when the toggle is pressed, and then in `Activity C` check the SharedPreferences for said value and act accordingly.